# How to find by id after lookup aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of news articles in mongodb and another collection that maps a user's ID to an article's ID and has a "like" state, which can be either "like" or "dislike" or "none" if no entry with the user and article exists.

Here are both schemas:

```
// news collection
const articleSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
})

// newslikes collection
const articleLikeSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client' },
  article: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'News' },
  state: { type: String, enum: ['like', 'dislike'] }
})
```

I'm trying to write an aggregation query which joins these two collection using `$lookup` and then finds the state of a specific user's like on all articles. This is what I have so far:

```
  const results = await News.aggregate([
    { $match: query },
    { $sort: { date: -1 } },
    { $skip: page * pageLength },
    { $limit: pageLength },
    { $lookup: {
      from: 'newslikes',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'article',
      as: 'likes'
    } },
    { $project: {
      title: 1,
      likes: 1,
      content: 1,
      // numLikes: { $size: '$likes' }
      userLikeStatus: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$likes',
          as: 'like',
          cond: {
            $eq: ['$user._id', '5ccf13adcec5e6d84f940417']
          }
        }
      }
    } }
  ])
```

However this is not working. Is what I'm doing even the correct approach or is there a better way to do this rather than `$filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can use below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above

```
News.aggregate([
  { "$match": query },
  { "$sort": { "date": -1 } },
  { "$skip": page * pageLength },
  { "$limit": pageLength },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "newslikes",
    "let": { "articleId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$article", "$$articleId" ] },
        "user": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ccf13adcec5e6d84f940417")
      }}
    ],
    "as": "likes"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "userLikeStatus": { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$likes.state", 0] }, "none"] }
  }}
])
```

Or the way you are trying

Basically here you need to put [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) for the field `userLikeStatus` i.e if the [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the array after [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) is [**`$gte`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) 1 then user likes it else does not.

```
News.aggregate([
  { "$match": query },
  { "$sort": { "date": -1 } },
  { "$skip": page * pageLength },
  { "$limit": pageLength },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "newslikes",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "article",
    "as": "likes"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "title": 1,
    "likes": 1,
    "content": 1,
    // numLikes: { $size: '$likes' }
    "userLikeStatus": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "array": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$likes",
              "as": "like",
              "cond": { "$eq": ["$$like.user", mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5ccf13adcec5e6d84f940417")] }
            }
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$$array.state", 0] }, "none"]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have a `$cond` and then a `$gt` and a `$filter` inside it

Comment: Also I'm getting an error for the first approach: `$in requires an array as a second argument, found: objectId`

Comment: This isn't really what I want. I want the like status string which is either "like" or "dislike" or "none" if the row doesn't exist. I don't want a simple Boolean value

Comment: Well I do not test most of the time. Most of the syntax I have just remembered. I had tested the code which I had posted yesterday but now I am busy and not able to test it. Give me a last try. If you would have posted the real data and the sample output then till I would have answered you correctly.